# error: incompatible types in assignment of unions

Tags: c, unions

I have some piece of code. For compiling I use gcc compiler.

```
union uStackElement {
              int i; 
              double d; 
}
typedef union uStackElement StackElement;

...
StackElement stack_pop(Stack s);
...
StackElement a = stack_pop(Stack s); // error: incompatible types in assignment
...
```

I can't get what's wrong. :(

UPD:
Stack definition:

```
struct sStack
{
        int top ;
        StackElement array[STACK_SIZE];
};
typedef struct sStack Stack;
```

function stack_pop :

```
StackElement stack_pop(Stack s) {
        StackElement ret;
        if (s.top < 0) {
                // TODO : error
        }
        ret = s.array[s.top--];
        return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this is your error:

```
union uStackElement {
          int i; 
          double d; 
} // << missing semicolon
```

That being said, there are a number of other problems, such as needing to pass the `Stack` object as a pointer if you are going to mutate it.

---

The following code compiles successfully, which is all you have shown at this point.

```
#define STACK_SIZE 10

union uStackElement {
    int i; 
    double d; 
};
typedef union uStackElement StackElement;

struct sStack
{
    int top;
    StackElement array[STACK_SIZE];
};
typedef struct sStack Stack;

StackElement stack_pop(Stack s) {
    StackElement ret;
    if (s.top < 0) {
        // TODO : error
    }
    ret = s.array[s.top--];
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    Stack s;
    StackElement a = stack_pop(s);
}
```

If the above code does **not** look like your code, then you need to edit your question such that I can take your code, and run it through a compiler and see the error for myself. Otherwise, it's very possible that the code that you don't include is actually where the error is.

Comment: Without semicolon it would have given a wall of errors and warnings.

Comment: @zubergu: I simply get: `foo.c:6:2: error: expected ';' after union`, but I agree that the error that is proposed is not what I would expect.